# How to make the particles' track to be a rectangle by particle designer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, particle-system

It is easy to generate particles to make their trajectory to be a circle by using particle designer.My problem is how to make the track to be a rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to move the individual particles from one corner of a rectangle to another, then the answer is: You can't.

You can however move the particle system itself. If the system spawns particles with no speed/direction (ie particles stay in place) and you move enough particle system instances in rectangular fashion yourself (ie with sequenced CCMoveTo) you may be able to achieve what you want.